# How to combine two tables and then extract timestamp difference as an extra column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables which I would like to query. I am using:

```
select timesheet_id, start_time, end_time, break_type, name 
from table1, table2
```

to produce the list of results that I want.

However, I also need to subtract `start_time (timestamp)` from `end_time (timestamp)` and add the result as an extra column.

So far I have only managed to come up with:

```
select extract(epoch from (end_time - start_time))/60
from table1
```

to get the subtraction, but I am lost as to how I can do this when pulling data from both tables?

Comment: You are missing a proper `JOIN` in your first query. Never use a comma in the FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

This seems very simply.

You just have to add your secod query expression in the first query as follows:

```
select timesheet_id, start_time, end_time, break_type, name,
       extract(epoch from (end_time - start_time))/60 as diff
  from table1, table2
```